# unable to send message to connections using Linkedin API's

Tags: java, linkedin-api

We are trying to send messages to our connections in LinkedIn using the Developer APIs. We are following the steps as provided in the developer site documentation.

However, when we create an app with LinkedIn it gives access to parameters such as `r_emailaddress`, `r_basicprofile`, `w_member_social`. We would like to understand how to enable permissions for `w_messages` using LinkedIn v2 API's, Kindly point us in the right direction.